# C sending allocated strings through named pipe - linux

Tags: c, linux

I want to send allocated strings through named pipes, not simple char arrays.

I got the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int pid, fd;
    fd = mkfifo("fifo.ftc", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    pid = fork();

    char* send, * recieve;

    if(pid == 0) {
        recieve = malloc(100);
        fd = open("fifo.ftc", O_RDONLY);
        read(fd, recieve, sizeof(recieve));
        close(fd);
        printf("%s\n", recieve);

        send = malloc(100);
        send = "This text was sent by child!";
        fd = open("fifo.ftc", O_WRONLY);
        write(fd, send, sizeof(send));
        close(fd);

        free(recieve);
        free(send);

    } else if(pid > 0) {
        send = malloc(100);
        send = "This text was sent by parent!";
        fd = open("fifo.ftc", O_WRONLY);
        write(fd, send, sizeof(send));
        close(fd);

        recieve = malloc(100);
        fd = open("fifo.ftc", O_RDONLY);
        read(fd, recieve, sizeof(recieve));
        close(fd);
        printf("%s\n", recieve);

        unlink("fifo.ftc");

        free(send);
        free(recieve);
    }
}
```

As an output, I always recieve:

```
This tex
This tex
```

It looks like it doesn't print the whole strings out. How to recieve the whole messages from the parent and the child?

Comment: Note `sizeof recieve` is probably 8 (recieve is a pointer. Same for `sizeof send` (which is a badvariable name, IMHO)

Comment: `read` won't null-terminate the string read in too, so you need to do that. and also the size given should be 1 less than allocated to accommodate that NUL character

Comment: Only the characters of the string go over the pipe, not the string as an object in its own right.  In this sense, there is no difference between sending an array and sending a dynamically allocated buffer.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple mistakes in your code.

1. You have to keep in mind that both [read](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) and [write](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write) don't guarantee they will effectively read or write the amount of bytes you told them to.

   From the Linux write man page:

   > **Synopsis**
   >
   > #include <unistd.h>
   >
   > ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
   >
   > **Description**
   >
   > write() writes up to count bytes from the buffer pointed buf to the
   >   file referred to by the file descriptor fd. ***The number of bytes
   >   written may be less than count if***, for example, there is insufficient
   >   space on the underlying physical medium, or the RLIMIT_FSIZE resource
   >   limit is encountered (see setrlimit(2)), or the call was interrupted
   >   by a signal handler after having written less than count bytes. (See
   >   also pipe(7).)

   They return how many bytes they have read or written, so you must store their return value in a variable and handle that accordingly. You'd generally wrap them in a loop, keep a counter that accumulates how many bytes were read/written, and exit the loop when it reaches the original buffer size, or when an error value is returned.
2. As mentioned by @wildplasser in comments, you are misusing the `sizeof` operator. When you do `char *foo; sizeof foo;`, the resulting size is not the size of the string pointed by `foo`, but the size of the char pointer type (8 bytes in 64 bits architecture, 4 bytes in 32 bits). You should use `strlen(foo)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

@jweyrich has already answered the main point of your question.  However there are some other points that you might consider...

String assignments in C are sometimes a confusion point when getting started with the language as there are occasions when assignments such as:

```
send = "This text was sent by parent!";
```

will work, and others when it will not.  It works in this case because the variable `send` in your code was created as a pointer.  Keep in mind if it had been created as an array, the only time an assignment could have been made using an `=` operator would have been during initialization.  Post initialization assignments to the `char array` form of a C string must be made differently.  Commonly the string functions (`strcpy`, `strcat`, `sprintf`, etc) are used to modify, or make assignments to strings;  Examples:

```
//string literal used to initialize
char send[100] = "This text was sent by parent!"; //works

//initialized with nul terminator
char send[100] = '\0';
//post initialization statements:
strcpy(send, "This text was sent by parent!");//works
strcat(send, "This text was sent by parent!");//works
sprintf(send, "%s", "This text was sent by parent!");//works
```

but:

```
send = "This text was sent by parent!"; //does not work;
```

*[More on strings here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)*

Also, it is recommended that you always check the return of `malloc()` to make sure memory was indeed allocated:

```
send = malloc(100);
if(!send) return -1; //check return of malloc
send = "This text was sent by parent!";
```

One other point: because `recieve` is a pointer, it's size will be the number of bytes required to contain its address, probably 4 bytes for a 32 bit target, or 8 bytes for a 64bit target.  So the statement:

```
read(fd, recieve, sizeof(recieve));
```

is very likely telling read to read 4 or 8 bytes, which is not likely what you expected.  Change this line to:

```
read(fd, recieve, 100);
```